# Pedir la hora en un AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-studio

Lo que quiero es tener un EditText que cuando lo presionen se despliegue un diálogo en el que escoja la hora y los minutos. El cuadro de dialogo me sale, pero al darle en la opción aceptar me sale el clásico "Lamentablemente la app se detuvo"...

Esto es lo que tengo hecho hasta ahora...

```
public class Activity_llamadas extends Activity {

Button boton;
EditText editText;
TextView textView;
int h=0;
int m=0;


@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_llamadas);

    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewHora);
    final TimePicker timePicker= (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePickerInicio);
     boton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonActHora);
     boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
          int hora= timePicker.getCurrentHour();
          int min=timePicker.getCurrentMinute();textView.setText(String.valueOf(hora)+": "+String.valueOf(min)); //aqui me funciona bien

         }
     });
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.getHora);
    editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showTime();
        }
    });

} public void showTime(){
   AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
   builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_set_time,null))
           .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) { // EL PROBLEMA ESTA AQUI 
                  final TimePicker timePicker= (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
                   TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewHora);
                        h=timePicker.getCurrentHour();
                        m=timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
                   textView.setText(String.valueOf(h)+": "+String.valueOf(m));  //textView donde pongo la hora

               }
           });
           builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { //esto tambien funciona bien
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Por favor, seleccione una hora",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           });
   AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
   alert.show(); }}`
```

Esto es lo que me muestra el logCat con el filtro de error:

```
02-18 17:59:29.750 17266-17266/com.example.andry.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.andry.myapplication, PID: 17266
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                 at com.example.andry.myapplication.Activity_llamadas$3.onClick(Activity_llamadas.java:70)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

La linea 70 es esta: h=timePicker.getCurrentHour();

GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO

Comment: he agregado una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

te falta el método para seleccionar hora/minuto, que es este:

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) { // EL PROBLEMA ESTA AQUI
     final TimePicker timePicker= (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
     timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
         TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewHora);
         //h = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
         //m = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
         textView.setText(String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ": " + String.valueOf(minute));  //textView donde pongo la hora
        }
   });
```

Comment: Amigo, ya lo intente pero me sigue poniendo lo mismo...no conoces otra variante, ahora me hace referencia el logcat a esta linea....  timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener()

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que trata de obtener valores de hora y minutos de una instancia TimePicker que no existe:

```
 h=timePicker.getCurrentHour();
 m=timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
```

En este caso debes asegurar que el `TimePicker` con id `timePicker` se encuentre en el layout `dialog_set_time.xml` que carga tu `AlertDialog`.

Si aseguras lo anterior entonces ahora revisar que obtienes el `TimePicker` del Dialogo:

```
final TimePicker timePicker= (TimePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

     TextView textView=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.textViewHora);

      h=timePicker.getCurrentHour();
      m=timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
```

Comment: Si, ya lo comprobé, y en ese layout es donde esta el TimePicker con id timePicker. Imagino que debe de ser ese el problema, pero como ya te dije SI eso que me dices ya lo comprobé y esta bien..Alguna otra idea??

Comment: En el logCat debe mostrar una linea que dice "Caused by", que dice completamente?

Comment: No, lo siento pero no sale ninguna linea que diga "Caused by"

Comment: Trata nuevamente y dime el AlertDialog con el TimePicker si se muestra? porque si no se muestra esto también puede causar el problema.

Comment: Si, si se muestra

Comment: busca el timepicker en el dialogo cambia a esta linea: final TimePicker timePicker= (TimePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

Comment: Me selecciona en rojo findViewById...me dice "Cannot resolve method findViewById(int)".

Answer (score 0):

Ya resolví el problema lo que hice fue trabajar con la clase TimePickerDialog. El método para obtener la hora y mostrar en un TextView me quedo de la siguiente forma:

```
private void mostrarHora(final TextView t) {
    final TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,int minute) {
                 int h= view.getCurrentHour();
                 int  m = view.getCurrentMinute();
                   setTxHora(h,m,t);
                }
            }, h, m, false);
    timePickerDialog.setTitle("Selecciona la hora");
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
```

El método setxHora() es el encargado de recibir un TextView la hora y los minutos y escribirlos en el TextView pasado por parámetro también